# React useEffect runs twice (not on StrictMode)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm building an app that works with sockets, so running twice is a real issue. I'm having some "race" problems and some emits and up registering twice.

I've noticed that the useEffect in which I have the emit runs twice. I couldn't figure out why, so decided to simplify things an replace that page with a much simpler test page and see if the use effect still runs twice. It does, and I can't understand why.

I will list down all the relevant code.

index.tsx (no StrictMode)

```
const container = document.getElementById("root")!;
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

src/App.tsx

```
export function App() {

  return (
    <Wrapper data-test="app">
      <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
      <Route path="/test" element={<TestPage />} />
      <Route path="/join-room" element={<JoinRoomPage />} />
      <Route path="/:id" element={<RoomPage />} />
      <Route path="/admin-add-answer" element={<AdminAddAnswerPage />} />
      <Route path="/admin-add-question" element={<AdminAddQuestionPage />} />
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

src/wrapper

```
export const Wrapper: React.FunctionComponent<WrapperProps> = (
  props: WrapperProps
): React.ReactElement<WrapperProps> => {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState<User>();
  const [room, setRoom] = React.useState<Room>();
  const [round, setRound] = React.useState<Round>();

  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter data-test="wrapper-router">
        <Provider store={store} data-test="wrapper-store-provider">
          <SocketProvider>
            <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
              <RoomContext.Provider value={{ room, setRoom }}>
                <RoundContext.Provider value={{ round, setRound }}>
                  <Box
                    sx={{
                      fontFamily: "main",
                      height: "100vh",
                      width: "100vw",
                      position: "relative",
                    }}
                  >
                    <Routes data-test="wrapper-routes">{props.children}</Routes>
                  </Box>
                </RoundContext.Provider>
              </RoomContext.Provider>
            </UserContext.Provider>
          </SocketProvider>
        </Provider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};
```

So this is the basic setup. Now I have the home page where the user opens a new room (building a multiplayer online game). I send the request and make sure to only navigate to the test page after the user object is set in the context and also after getting the success confirmation (I'm using RTK Query).

Note: I split my components for container/presentational, where container holds any logic/state and presentational is purely, well, presentational component. So I'm not including the code for that.

src/pages/home

```
export const HomeContainer = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [createRoom, { isSuccess, data }] = useCreateRoomMutation();

  const socket = useContext(SocketContext);
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);

  const [settings, setSettings] = useState({
    points_to_win: 10,
    max_time_per_round: 15,
  });


  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSuccess && user) {
      navigate(`/test`);
    }
  }, [isSuccess, data, navigate, user]);

  const handleSubmit = (settings: {
    points_to_win: number;
    max_time_per_round: number;
  }) => {
    try {
      const newUser = {
        _id: uuidv4(),
        is_tv: true,
        nickname: "main_projector",
      };
      sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(newUser));
      setUser(newUser);
      createRoom({ projector_id: socket.id, settings });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Failed to create a new room", e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <HomePresentational
      handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
      onClickJoin={() => navigate("/join-room")}
      settings={settings}
      setSettings={(s: { points_to_win: number; max_time_per_round: number }) =>
        setSettings(s)
      }
    />
  );
};
```

And then finally

src/pages/test

```
export const TestContainer = () => {
  console.log("test container");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("test container useEffect");
  }, []);
  return <Box>This is test container</Box>;
};
```

After opening a new room, and being automatically directed to the test page, this is what I get logged:

```
test-container.tsx:5 test container
test-container.tsx:8 test container useEffect
test-container.tsx:8 test container useEffect
```

Comment: You could return a function from the effect to check if it is being unmounted and re-mounted: `return () => { console.log("unmount") };` 
If that's the case, then it's probably somewhere up the component tree.

Comment: You still have StrictMode in your Wrapper btw.

Comment: @zirkelc thank you for suggesting, it does unmount

Comment: @Rango oh god. That was it. Can't believe it flew by me thank you. Closed